# how to get Activity Context in jni?(only using env)

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to make alertDialog in jni lib, But I couldn't make it because I can't get activity context so there's error like "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?".

```cpp
static jobject getContext2(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jclass activityThread = (*env).FindClass("com/~~~/~~~/MainActivity");
    jmethodID getbasecontext = (*env).GetMethodID(activityThread,"getBaseContext","()Landroid/content/Context;");
    jobject context1 = getContext(env);
    jobject context = (*env).CallObjectMethod(context1, getbasecontext);
    return context;
}
```

I tried it too, but It didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could keep a reference to the currently active `Activity` in some singleton that your native code can reach. But this doesn't really seem like a good idea. Why can't your native function just return/send some status to your java code which then handles showing the dialog?